# Any vim-plugin to access system clipboard on as many unix platforms as possible?

Tags: plugin-system, os-clipboard

There are many question regarding this on SE and various solutions have been provided on how to access system clipboard on various platforms. I `ssh` to various machines and on some platforms, my clipboard and vim stop playing well (specially over shh).

Is there a plugin to which makes vim access the system clipboard on almost all Linux, MacOSX, and puTTy (with `ssh -X`) ?

Comment: `ssh -Y` might work for you

Answer (score 2):

I've not heard of such a plugin (doesn't mean it doesn't exist). But I can lay out an alternative approach...

Instead of dealing with multiple systems and their disparate clipboard configurations use your local `vim` (+netrw) to edit remote files. Since you mention accessing remote systems with `ssh` then `vim` can use `scp`, for one. Let's say you want to update a text file in a remote home directory...

```
:Nread scp://my.name@example.com/~/file.txt
```

Or even...

```
:e scp://my.name@example.com/~/file.txt
```

Works from the command line, too. (`$ vim scp://etc`).

Now you can cut and paste to your heart's content using just the local clipboard.

Other protocols are available including these (`:h netrw-read` for complete list):

```
:Nread "ftp://[user@]machine[[:#]port]/path"    uses ftp w/ <.netrc>
:Nread "http://[user@]machine/path"             uses http
:Nread "rsync://[user@]machine[:port]/path"     uses rsync
:Nread "scp://[user@]machine[[:#]port]/path"    uses scp
```

[More remote editing tips](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Editing_remote_files_via_scp_in_vim)

---

If your workflow is more along the lines of impromptu use of `vim` while you're doing work on the command line of a remote machine then check out out [bcvi](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/bcvi). Install this standalone script on a remote machine and then when you do `vi file.txt` on the remote (e.g. during an `ssh` session) your *local* `[g]vim` will open the remote file automatically using the same underlying mechanism as described above.

Some outside the box thinking for you.

Comment: `bcvi` looks very promising. Thanks for mentioning it.